# Serialization events in Kryo

Tags: kryo

How do you receive serialization events? You can define

```
void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) {
  // handle event
  out.defaultWriteObject(this);
}
```

in java serialization and this method will be called when your object is serialized. How do you do the same thing in Kryo? Both `KryoSerializable` and `Externalizable` have the problem of default serialization: once you invoked your event handler, you want the default read/write object. But there is no such thing! ? You may invoke `FieldSerializer` in `read(Kryo, Input)` to read the fields of the object, but it will produce you a new object instead of populating the current one. For this reason, I tried to introduce a custom serializer:

```
Serializer def = kryo.getDefaultSerializer(A.class)
kryo.addDefaultSerializer(A.class, new Serializer() {
    public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, Object object) {
        ((A)object).serializationEvent();
        def.write(kryo, output, object);
```

But, I mentioned that through subclasses of A receive the `serializationEvent()` event, only A.class fields are serialized. So, this does not work for `class B extends A`. I also tried the solution [proposed by Natan](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=86): `register(A.class, new FieldSerializer(A.class, myhandler`. This serializes all fields, including subclasses, but, the custom serializer is not invoked for subclasses at all. So, I decided that Kryo customization works only for final classes. [Nathan says that this conclusion is "invalid" and KryoSerializable solution "application-specific" and thinking otherwise "rude".](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=86) Despite of such resolution, I decided to publish the general method I discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered two solutions. At first, overriding writeReferenceOrNull can work

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo() {
    public boolean writeReferenceOrNull (Output output, Object object, boolean mayBeNull) {
        if (object instanceof A) {
            ((A) object).serializationEvent();
        }

        return super.writeReferenceOrNull(output, object, mayBeNull);
    }
```

But, it needs source code visibility change and Natan says that this works only when references are enabled (in the default case) and recommends a more reliable approach instead: overriding the newDefaultSerializer:

```
public class EventFiringKryo extends Kryo {
    protected Serializer newDefaultSerializer(Class type) {
        final Serializer def = super.newDefaultSerializer(type);
        Serializer custom = new Serializer() {

            public void write(Kryo kryo, Output output, Object object) {
                System.err.println("writing " + object + ":" + object.getClass().getSimpleName());
                if (object instanceof A)
                    ((A)object).serializationEvent();
                def.write(kryo, output, object);
            }

            public Object read(Kryo kryo, Input input, Class type) {
                Object result = def.read(kryo, input, type);
                if (result instanceof SomeAnotherType)
                    result.canInitializeSomethingElse();
                return result;
            }
        };
        return custom;
    }

}
```

In addition to being effective, this method does not suffer from the need to carefully register all classes that implement the interface that you are going to invoke.